# returnを拡張した上で、その機能を呼び出す方法

Tags: emacs, elisp

趣味で現在、エンターキーを叩くと音が鳴るように、自分のEmacsを拡張しています。そのときに、以下のようなEmacs Lispを書いています:

```
 (defun java-button ()
    (interactive)
    (progn
      (start-process
       "java-button-process"
       nil
       "aplay"
       (concat (getenv "HOME") "/Archive/" "java.wav"))
      ;; (newline) ???
      ))

  (global-set-key [return] 'java-button)
```

このとき、`global-set-key`の段階で、`java-button`という関数に上書きされてしまうため、元々ある`return`(エンターキー)の「バッファでのメニュー決定」などの機能が無くなってしまいます。

`newline`を使えばいいのかなとも思ったのですが、`Readonly-buffer`のエラーとなってしまい、そのバッファのテキスト内容を編集しようとしてしまいます。

この場合、`java-button`という関数(?)から何を呼び出すのが適切なのでしょうか。それとも本来はこのように書くべきではなく、他の上書きしないような回避方法があるのでしょうか?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

キー入力を監視するフック変数 `post-self-insert-hook` (または `post-command-hook`) を利用して、その中で `return` キーが押された場合に音を鳴らすのがよいかと思います。
この方法であれば元のキー定義を上書きする必要はありません。

```
(require 'cl-lib)

(defun user/play-sound-maybe ()
  (cl-case last-input-event
    ((?\C-m return)
     (java-button))))

(add-hook 'post-self-insert-hook 'user/play-sound-maybe)
```

関数名は適当に置き換えてください。

Answer (score 1):

Enterを押したときに限らず、newlineの実行時でよいなら次のような感じでどうでしょうか。

```
(defun advice-java-button (proc string)
  (start-process
   "java-button-process"
   nil
   "aplay"
   (concat (getenv "HOME") "/Archive/" "java.wav")))
(advice-add 'newline :before #'advice-java-button)
```